# Interface self-powered sensor with Particle Photon using 4-20 mA current receiver

Tags: arduino, 4-20ma

Is it possible to use 4-20 mA self-powered sensors using current receivers? If not, then what will be the best way to use these sensors and interface with Particle Photon to monitor the readings?

Note: a 4-20 mA current receiver is a new device and easy to use with IoT devices, and I am giving Particle a try.

Experienced suggestions on this will be helpful.

Comment: Can you please provide links and more description to what devices you are talking about?

Comment: Without more data from you: IF the sensor accepts a voltage, uses some of the voltage to power itself and then modulates the currentto 4-20 mA to return signal, then eg placing a resistor from negative return to ground will provide a voltage across the resistor proportional to current. Who needs a receiver ? :-). Placing a type unspecified link not provided easy to use if you have the spec sheet receiver where the resistor is probably works.

Comment: [Garglabet maybe relevant search](https://www.google.co.nz/search?num=50&source=hp&ei=uFrqWoe4FMic0gTdqKyoBw&q=self+powered+sensors+4-20+mA&oq=self+powered+sensors+4-20+mA&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i22i29i30k1l3.1453.7845.0.8034.30.25.0.0.0.0.549.4080.2-11j3j0j1.16.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..14.13.3546.6..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1j0i22i30k1j33i160k1.255.03ApWyIBnz8)

Comment: Many of [**these**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=self+powered+sensors+4-20+mA&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4wIy8p-jaAhUDlpQKHdd3AHUQsAR6BAgAECw&biw=1344&bih=696) may be relevant, [**This**](https://www.dataq.com/blog/data-acquisition/4-20-ma-current-loop-measurements/) provides  a good tutorial.

Comment: I am using (pressure sensor)[http://www.industrybuying.com/pressure-vacuum-switches-kavlico-PN.CO.PR.366241/?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=PLA&utm_campaign=PLA_Pneumatics&gclid=Cj0KCQjw5qrXBRC3ARIsAJq3bwpzy_2iJvFbrKg0_bd9_km1gGddAm81Glml-YIvYIZLwl4Q21r1xGQaAjWeEALw_wcB] which Is connected to 24v DC supply placing a 1.2K resistor across the output will this type connection will be okay to get it interface with IoT device or there will be some problem in it ? 

I am looking for module which will easily connect the sensor with particle photon

Answer (score 0):

Please provide links to equipment used.

Excellent tutorial [**here**](https://www.dataq.com/blog/data-acquisition/4-20-ma-current-loop-measurements/).
Images below are from the above web page.

For a sensor powered by the loop current / voltage: If the sensor accepts a voltage, uses some of the voltage to power itself and then modulates the current to 4-20 mA to return signal, then eg placing a resistor from negative return to ground will provide a voltage across the resistor proportional to current. Who needs a receiver ? :-).

[image]

If the sensor has its own power supply then placing a resistor across the output will provide a voltage proportional to current. Who needs a receiver ? :-).

[image]

In both cases a receiver in place of the resistor should provide a useful signal.

Many of [**these**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=self+powered+sensors+4-20+mA&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4wIy8p-jaAhUDlpQKHdd3AHUQsAR6BAgAECw&biw=1344&bih=696) may be relevant, [**This**](https://www.dataq.com/blog/data-acquisition/4-20-ma-current-loop-measurements/) provides  a good tutorial.